# Firebase add custom Domain - Edit Domain show Error

Tags: reactjs, dns, firebase-hosting, firebase-console

When I try to add a custom domain ti Firebase, the edit domain page shoe a warning in red - One or more of Hosting's HTTP GET request for the ACME challenge failed: 168.119.66.98: 404 Not Found

What is causing it and how can I correct it.

I did change the DNS entries as per the edit page but the error still show

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Below Error was displayed on a coloured background at the top

`One or more of Hosting's HTTP GET request for the ACME challenge failed: 15.197.148.33: 404 Not Found, 3.33.130.190: 404 Not Found`

I was able to resolve this firebase custom domain setup error by logging out from all my Single sign-on sessions
(Login with gmail etc) and, login again in new tab, with gmail id /password it worked